# Koa - Cleaner Async way to serve static files?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, bluebird, koa

```
var app = require('koa')();
var router = require('koa-router')();    
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

router
  .get('*', function *(next) {
    fs.readFileAsync('static/home.html','utf8')
      .then(function(data){ 
          console.log(data)
      });
  });

koa.use(router.routes());

koa.listen(8888);
```

I have the above working as I'd like using bluebird promises, however, is there a more sync-esque-looking way (while still being async) of doing it?

A-la:

```
router
  .get('*', function *(next) {
    var data = fs.readFile('static/home.html','utf8');
    console.log(data);
  });
```

I was planning to use thunks at first, but read that co was not going to continue support for it. So is there another way to do this? Like using generators or something?
I know I can yield the above function to pause, but that doesn't guarantee that the operation will have finished by the time it comes back right?

Comment: What's wrong with the promise implementation?  You want to be using async IO in any server, so the last thing you want to do is switch to synchronous IO.  I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Oh no switching, still sticking with async, just formatting preferences. [this](http://colintoh.com/blog/staying-sane-with-asynchronous-programming-promises-and-generators#run-to-completion) is what I'm hoping to make the code look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`co` will yield to promises, so you're second example is almost perfect. You probably just need to add a `yield` statement to your `fs.readFileAsync` call. Like this:

```
router
  .get('*', function *(next) {
    var data = yield fs.readFileAsync('static/home.html','utf8');
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: This is the answer. Promises are yieldable by co. Wrapping a traditional callback-based function with a promise so that you can yield it in a route is exactly what you're supposed to do in Koa.

Comment: Error: "You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, etc..."  
That's why I'm having to use BlueBird to promisify fs. Though @Freyday's answer works if 'readFileAsync' is used in conjunction with BlueBird. Ah, well, good enough I suppose.

Comment: @House3272 Oh, right. Yeah, you'll have to use `yield fs.readFileAsync` as that's the promise version of the function that Bluebird injects into the module. It's a good thing because it doesn't trample on the existing module functions, and sometimes you'll want to use the original, unmodified callback-style functions in the same file that you use the promisified `*Async` version.